# $scope.data in controller function is undefined (ANGULARJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a function that creates a group by POSTing to an api but now im trying to get that function to append the newly created group to the users feed without the need of refreshing the page. I know i have to to do a .push and push the data to the array, but im having an issue where on .success(function(data) {} $scope.data comes back undefined so im unable to push the data to the $scope.feeds array. Any suggestions?

```
hello.controller('FeedListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$cookies', '$modal', '$log', 'FeedService', 
function FeedListCtrl($scope, $http, $window, $cookies, $modal, $log, FeedService, $modalInstance) {

    $(function() {
        $('.ns-notify').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('body').css("padding", "40px 0");
    });     

$scope.feeds = [];


    $scope.createGroupCall = function createGroupCall(teacher, name) {
            $modalInstance.close();
            FeedService.createGroupCall($cookies.token, $window.sessionStorage.user, teacher, name).success(function(data) {

            console.log('GroupCreated');
            console.log(data.name);
            console.log(data.teacher);
            console.log($scope.create);
            console.log($scope.data + "THIS IS SCOPE.DATA");
            console.log($scope.feeds + 'HEY!');
            $scope.feeds.push($scope.data);
            $scope.feedCall($cookies.token);
        }).error (function(status,data,token) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        });

};

$scope.feedCall = function feedCall(token) {
    FeedService.feedCall(token).success(function(data) {
        $scope.feeds = data.results;

        console.log("FEED Controller")
        // console.log(data);
        console.log(data.results);
        console.log($scope.feeds);
    }).error (function(status,data,token) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
    });
}

$scope.feedCall($cookies.token);
}]);


<div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="CreateGroupContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title ns-modal-title">Create A Group</h2>
                <button class="ns-modal-close" ng-click="cancel()"><img src="images/xCancel.png"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-signin" role="form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ns-modal-form" placeholder="Teacher" ng-model="create.teacher" required autofocus>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ns-modal-form" placeholder="Group Name" ng-model="create.name" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary ns-modal-add" ng-click="createGroupCall(create.teacher, create.name);" type="submit">Create</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

i am using bootstraps angular-ui plugin for my modals that should explain $modal, $modalInstance and $log

even though $scope.data is coming back undefined if i console.log(data) i actually get the data back.

Comment: I don't see where you assigned `$scope.data` to anything?  `$scope.data` and `data` are 2 different objects.

Comment: where is ng-repeat part, can you setup a plunker